# slf4j logger is not printing the log in console for springboot if wrapped under log.isDebugEnabled()

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, slf4j

I am using slf4j logger in my controller class, even though my application.properties has the following entries:

```
#logging.level.*= DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.com.ge.power.brs.controllers.*=DEBUG
```

The code looks like :

```
 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventControllerV1.class);

public ResponseEntity<List<EventView>> requestEvents(@RequestParam("user_name") String userName) throws Exception { 
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug("EventControllerV1:::requestEvents:::Parameters>>::userName::" + userName);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(eventManager.findEvents(userName), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**

In the background slf4j uses Logback framework, but still I am not able to get the console output..but if I remove the condition and use log.info("xxx") only , I can see the output in console when I hit the endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
  log.info("xxx") ;
}
```

Doesn't make much sense.

instead, it should be

```
if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
  log.debug("xxx") ;
}
```

## And to answer your original question,

this is not working

```
if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
  log.info("xxx") ;
}
```

and this is working `log.info("xxx") ;`

then that means, Log level for that class and method is at INFO level (which is higher than DEBUG). Try removing the * from `logging.level.com.ge.power.brs.controllers.*=DEBUG`

Comment: In the application.properties file there is entry for `logging.level.com.ge.power.brs.controllers.EventControllerV1=DEBUG` in which is the class where I placed the log statement, it then prints but if I give `logging.level.com.ge.power.brs.controllers.* = DEBUG` , it does not print. Any idea why I have to explicitly name the class

Comment: try removing the *

Answer (score 2):

Inside "src/main/resources/application.properties" file, add this:

```
logging.level.com.mypackage.name=INFO
```

So for example:

```
logging.level.com.yourbusiness=INFO
```

If you want it all, then try

```
logging.level.com=INFO
```

The ".com" part refers to anything inside src/main/java/com. So for my project, I have src/main/java/com/yourbusiness

Comment: still facing similar issue.                                                                                         @Override
    public void afterScenario(ScenarioResult result, ScenarioContext context) {
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).info("The Result of Scenario",result.getError());
}   still only The Result of sccenario is getting printed without error

Comment: It's getting printed. Check if ScenarioResult's result has been initialized.